# How to show the answer in terms of another variable

Tags: hold, variable

if we have

A = 1;
B = 44 + 1

output :: B = 45

how we can show B like this

output :: B = 44  + A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Hold`, `HoldComplete`, `Unevaluate`, or `Defer`.

work for your case `Hold`, `HoldComplete`, or `Defer`.

Best work for your case `Defer`

```
a = 1;
b = 44 + a // Defer

(* Output 44 + a *)
```

However using `Hold` and `HoldComplete` gives

```
a = 1; 
b = 44 + a // HoldComplete

(* Output HoldComplete[44 + a] *)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Reduce[{a == 1, b == 45, b == x + a}, x, {a, b}]

(* Out: x == 44 *)
```